# Independent variables, normal distribution, pdf

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have independent variables $ X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n $ with normal distribution on range $ [0,1] $ . Next, variables $ Z_i $ are created according to this formula
$ Z_i = - \frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(1-X_i) $ , where $ \lambda > 0 $. How to find probability density function of $ W = \max (Z_1 , \ldots , Z_n ) $  ?

After comments :
So, I have a formula $ f_Z(z) = | \frac{d}{dz} (1-e^{-\lambda z}) | f_X(1-e^{-\lambda z})  $ , but $ f_X (x) = 1 $ , so
$ f_Z(z) = 1 + \lambda e^{-\lambda z} $
And it represents all $ Z_i $

Comment: Do you mean uniform distribution?  The normal distribution isn't bounded.

Comment: my mistake, it should be unbounded

Comment: @user3676690 : You're being quite unclear.  You say "normal distribution on range $[0,1]$ and then in comments that that's a mistake and it should be unbounded.  That leaves the question of which normal distribution it is.  Then you have $\ln(1-X_i)$, which does not exist if $X_i>1$, which makes it look as if restricting it to $[0,1]$ makes sense, but then of course it's not normally distributed.  Could you edit the post to make it clear what you meant?

Comment: Later you say $f_X(x)=1$, so apparently you _did_ mean the uniform distribution, so your comment that it should be unbounded makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every maximum $W$ of random variables, one has, for every $w$,
$$
[W\lt w]=\bigcap_{i=1}^n[Z_i\lt w].
$$
If $(Z_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is i.i.d. and distributed as $Z$, then, for every $w$,
$$
P(W\lt w)=\prod_{i=1}^nP(Z_i\lt w)=P(Z\lt w)^n.
$$
In your case, considering $X$ distributed as $X_1$,
$$
[Z\lt w]=[\ln(1-X)\gt-\lambda w]=[X\lt1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda w}],
$$
hence, for every $w\gt0$,
$$
F_W(w)=F_Z(w)^n=F_X(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda w})^n.
$$
If every $X_i$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $F_X(x)=x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ hence, for every $w\gt0$,
$$
F_W(w)=(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda w})^n.
$$
Then the PDF $f_W$ is obtained by differentiation, that is,
$$
f_W(w)=n\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda w}(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda w})^{n-1}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}.
$$

Comment: why $ P(\forall i,Z_i\lt w)=P(Z_1\lt w)^n.
$$ $

Comment: Thank you, I have to go, but I'll check it and answer in  2-3 hours

Answer (score 0):

If $Z = \varphi(X)$, then $X = \varphi^{-1}(Z) = 1-e^{- \lambda Z}$ and $\frac{dX}{dz} = 1 +\lambda e^{- \lambda z}$. Now use the definition of the function of random variables.

Comment: I don't understand why you calculate $ X $ . How it help to find pdf of $ Z $

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: I updated my question. Now I have pdf of each $ Z_i $, but each is given by the same formula, so how to get maximum ?

Comment: what maximum are you talking about? you wanted pdf of a function of rv

Comment: sorry, I didn't write all in my question. I updated it again

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you meant the *uniform* distribution on $[0,1]$.  If $0<X<1$ then $Z=-\ln(1-X)>0$.  Then we have
$$
\Pr(Z\le z) = \Pr(-\ln(1-X)\le z) =  \Pr(X\le 1-e^{-z}) = 1-e^{-z}.
$$
So
$$
\Pr(\max\{Z_1,\ldots,Z_n\} \le z ) = \Pr(Z_1\le z\  \&\ \cdots\  \&\  Z_n\le z)
$$
$$
= (\Pr(Z_1\le z))^n = (1-e^{-z})^n.
$$
Differentiate to get the density function.